# Images disappearing with net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-content-length

I have some images that I cropped in Mac's Preview, and rotated with a tool called Jhead. These images now only appear on my site for ~20s, and then disappear and in the console there is this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3444/assets/01_shev-b380f94818b4bfbb6e0cb83719155995ea2a32dbbb24c7369dc8b93a3b9c2f33.jpg net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
```

I'm guessing my edits messed with the exif data, and somehow that makes the image think it's a different size to what it actually is? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

UGH ok so this was fixed simply by touching all the files:

```
touch app/assets/images/*.jpg
```